# Neos CMS 7: How to make a content element not editable in Neos UI?

Tags: neoscms

I have an article document type, that displays a slider with related articles at the bottom. This slider Fusion component should not be inline editable nor selectable at all (if possible). I would like to apply a similar behaviour as for non-inline-editable node elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Neos.Fusion:Component` to render elements without any backend logic.

### BACKGROUND:

If your component inherits from Neos.Neos:ContentComponent, it will be selectable in the backend and also editable if you use Neos.Neos:Editable inside. This is how it's implemented:

```
prototype(Neos.Neos:ContentComponent) < prototype(Neos.Fusion:Component) {
  # The following line must not be removed as it adds required meta data to all content elements in backend
  @process.contentElementWrapping {
    expression = Neos.Neos:ContentElementWrapping
    @position = 'end 999999999'
  }

  @exceptionHandler = 'Neos\\Neos\\Fusion\\ExceptionHandlers\\NodeWrappingHandler'
}
```